# Re-rendering the component after dispatching action from non-component JS file

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm dispatching the action from a non-component JS (utils/index.js) file using store.dispatch(), but after the reducer state change, the component in which that reducer state is connected using mapStateToProps is not being re-rendered,

What am i doing wrong?

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks in advance

> I tried searching through out and i went to all the questions and articles which are dispatching the action from a component file.

#### All the related files

**/store/index.js**

```
import { createStore } from "redux";
import rootReducer from "reducers";

store = createStore(rootReducer);
```

**/utils/index.js**

```
import store from './store';
import { toggleShowAlert } from "reducers/alert";

export const customAlert = msg => {
    store.dispatch(toggleShowAlert(msg));
}
```

**/views/Nav/index.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class Nav extends Component {
    render() {
        ....
        // component code
        ....
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        showAlert: state.alert.showAlert
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Nav);
```

**/reducer/alert.js**

```
const TOGGLE_SHOW_ALERT = "TOGGLE_SHOW_ALERT";

export const toggleShowAlert = msg => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch({
            type: TOGGLE_SHOW_ALERT,
            msg
        });
    };
};

const initialState = {
    showAlert: false,
    alertMsg: ""
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case TOGGLE_SHOW_ALERT:
            return {
                ...state,
                showAlert: !state.showAlert,
                alertMsg: state.showAlert ? "" : action.msg
            };
        default:
            return { ...state };
    }
}

export default reducer;
```

**another reducer from which that customAlert is being called**
**/reducers/user.js**

```
import { customAlert } from 'utils';

...other codes...

export const updateAgeGender = (userId, age, gender) => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(updateButtonLoading());
        callAPI("post", `${COMM_BE_URL}/users/update-age-gender`, {
            userId,
            age,
            gender
        })
        .then(res => {
            if (res.status === "SUCCESS") {
                dispatch(updateAgeGenderAction(age, gender));
                customAlert("Your info has been updated, now u can join");
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            dispatch(updateError(SERVER_ERROR_MSG));
        });
    };
};
```

After change of showAlert, the Nav Component should re-render, but it's not happening

Comment: why it should re-render? Components only re-render if THEIR state has changed, not if redux state has changed. You can force the render using shouldComponentUpdate(return true when your nextprops are different from the current ones) or componentWillReceiveProps(assign the new props to state)

Comment: @Drusto whenever a reducer state is update, then it re-renders the component to which it is connected using mapStateToProps . https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate#return

Comment: @Drusto, not true. Components, would also re-render if there props have changed. OP gets updated props when he calls the action.

Comment: @Aman, what are you actually expecting to see here? It looks like you are changing the redux-state. sure. But you don't seem to make use of the alert message at all.

Comment: @ChristopherNgo I'm expecting to re-render the Nav component after showAlert changes and in Nav, based on the showAlert value, logic varies i.e. whether to render a piece of code or not

Comment: @Aman. I've created a sandbox for you that does essentially the very same thing you are trying to do by using a non-component file to call a dispatch function, and have a component connected to the updated-reducer. https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-reactredux-flow-l9oq4... Everything works as expected, from what I can deduce, I don't see anything wrong with the code you suggested. Possible issue is where you are calling the utils function from.

Comment: @ChristopherNgo utils function is being called from another reducer

Comment: btw @ChristopherNgo, Thanks a lot for the effort

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194576/discussion-between-christopher-ngo-and-aman).